# Check if the key exists in the Redis list without retrieving the list

Tags: php, redis, pipeline

I'm using Redis for PHP.

I need to check if the key exists in redis list, and if it does not, add it. For now my code looks as follows:

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
$redis->pipeline(function($pipe)  use ($type, $redis)
    {
        $list = $pipe->lRange($type.'_unique_list', 0, -1);
        if(!in_array($this->uid, $list)) {
            $pipe->rPush($type . '_unique_list', $this->uid);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that `$list` taken from `$pipe` returns Redis object, not array, and `in_array` does not work. But if I use `$redis->lRange`, the script becomes too slow.

So my question is, if there is any possibility to **check if the key exists in Redis list without retrieving the list** into the script? Some special Redis command which I can't find in docs? Or maybe I could replace `in_array` with something else in this particular situation?

Comment: `$list` is object or object array? specify. better to show outout of `var_dump($list);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrongish answer: you can call [`LINDEX`](https://redis.io/commands/lindex) instead of doing the search in the client.

Righter answer: scanning a linked list is always an expensive operation (O(N)) whether it is server- or client-side. Consider using a different data structure, e.g. a Set, for that purpose if your N is large.

Comment: Yeah, I've discovered it already and just started just creating and checking separate small keys. Especially right thought, because I would have to flush this list once a while, while keys can expire automatically.